# Python: Create two dummy columns from one column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a one column Pandas dataframe:

```
'asdf'

0
1
1
1
0
...
1
```

How do I turn it into:

```
1    0
0    1
0    1
0    1
1    0
```

such that the first column is the "0" column and the second column is the "1" column and both are dummy variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get_dummies`, for example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

one = pd.DataFrame({'asdf':np.random.randint(0,2,10)})
two = pd.get_dummies(one.loc[:,'asdf'])
```